# Ember js dynamic action to toggle display using {{#if}} helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using some very simple actions to toggle content boxes in Ember:
(Working example here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/heyena/edit?html,css,js,output).

**index.hbs** (Template)

```html
<span {{action 'toggleBoxOne'}}>Toggle Box One</span>
<span {{action 'toggleBoxTwo'}}>Toggle Box Two</span>

{{#if One}}
<h3>Box 1</h3>
{{/if}}
<div class="clr"></div>
{{#if Two}}
<h3>Box 2</h3>
{{/if}}
```

**index.js** (Controller)

```js
actions: {
  toggleBoxOne: function() {
    this.set('Two', false);
    var showBox = this.get('One');
    if (showBox === false) {
      this.set('One', true);
    } else {
      this.set('One', false);
    }
  },
  toggleBoxTwo: function() {
    this.set('One', false);
    var showBoxTwo = this.get('showBoxTwo');
    if (showBoxTwo === false) {
      this.set('showBoxTwo', true);
    } else {
      this.set('showBoxTwo', false);
    }
  },

}, One: false, Two: false
```

I'm trying to create a single action, which can toggle different boxes based on arguments passed in the action handler:

```html
<span {{action 'toggleBox' 'One'}}>Toggle Box One</span>
<span {{action 'toggleBox' 'Two'}}>Toggle Box Two</span>
```

I would like to do something like the below,

```js
toggleBox: function(boxName) {
  var thisBox = boxName;
  if (thisBox === true) {
    this.set(thisBox, false);
  } else {
    this.set(thisBox, true);
  }
}, thisBox: false,
```

Is it possible to do this, while ensuring that showing one content box causes all others to disappear?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but you can just use `this.toggleProperty('One')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something very close to what you wanted:

```
toggleBox: function(boxName) {
  var thisBox = this.get(boxName);
    if (thisBox === true) {
      this.set(boxName, false);
    } else {
      this.set(boxName, true);
  }
}
```

But it's much easier to just do

```
this.set(boxName, !this.get(boxName))
```

which can be written even more compactly (and a bit more efficiently) as

```
this.toggleProperty(boxName)
```